# How to fix fixed sidebar side effect?

Tags: css, html, sidebar

I followed a tutorial/instructions online to make a sidebar fixed position by making the sidebars position "fixed" and it worked fine. Now I realize that since my page has a min-width attribute, when the user scrolls sideways the content that doesn't move moves into the sidebar. So basically, I'm looking for a way to produce a fixed sidebar when your scrolling down, but when you move sideways the content doesn't jump into the sidebar. My code is kind of like the following:

CSS

```
#sidebar {
    position:fixed;
    height:500px;
    width: 100px;
    background-color: blue;                    
}
#content {
    width:100%;
    box-sizing:border-box;
    margin-left:100px;
    background-color:purple;
}
```

​
Html

```
<div id="sidebar">
</div>
<div id="content">
</div>

​
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/znCF3/1/

NOTE: This is not my actually code but a minified version of it because my code is really complex. Also, I can't just use a fluid layout.

Comment: Your HTML code has a typo. Line two should be `</div>` instead of `<div>`. Is that the same as your source code?

Comment: No, my source code is much different and more complex, but It would have been confusing to post it all. Thanks

Comment: This is how `position:fixed` works, if you want to change that you'll need to do something else. Like add some javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As said by others, not possible with only css and html. However, you can do this with javascript/jquery.

Just encase you want to use jquery to do this, first as watson said, change index of side bar (I had to make negative), just encase it jquery doesn't work for whatever reason for someone.

Then add to your `<head>`:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
<script>
<!--
$(document).ready(function() {

    $(window).scroll(function(){ 
        var offSet = - ($(this).scrollLeft());
        $('#sidebar').css('left', offSet);
    });
});
//-->
</script>
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/znCF3/3/)

Answer (score 1):

Check out this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/NfKca/

Modified css as:

```
#sidebar {
    position:fixed;
    height:500px;
    width: 100px;
    background-color: blue;                    
}
#content {
    box-sizing:border-box;
    background-color:purple;
    position:absolute;
    left:100px;           
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but my layout can't be fluid (it sort of is but it has a min-width). Some of the elements just can't shrink.

Answer (score 0):

You could set the `z-index: 1;` on the sidebar. If this doesn't help, it would be great if you could make a jsfiddle to illustrate what you mean more.

Comment: so what is the problem in this situation?

Comment: @MikeG adding `position: relative` to `.content` would allow the content to sit above the side menu: http://jsfiddle.net/znCF3/2/

Comment: @Watson the problem will be that your answer does nothing. You would have to add `position: relative` to `.content` which would fix the problem. If you then added `z-indez: 1` to `.sidebar` then you would have the same problem again and you would have to add a larger `z-index` to `.content`